# React-hook setState does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I have the following code:

```
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data1, setData1] = useState([]);
  const [searchedString, setSearchString] = useState("");
  console.log(data1);

  const fetchDataHandler = async () => {
    setData1([]);

    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/select?articul=${searchedString}`)
      .then((response) => {
        dataStruction(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const dataStruction = (data) => {
    data.map((element1) => {
      if (element1.secondaryArt.startsWith("30")) {
        return setData1([...data1, { ...element1, level: 1 }]);
      }
    });
  };
  const onChangeSearchText = (event) => {
    setSearchString(event.target.value);
  };
```

I want whenever I call fetchDataHandler to be able to set data1 to empty array. Now it is working as that results are sticking every time I call fetchDataHandler. How can I do it?

Comment: it seems like everything you showed is fine. Why do you think `data1` isn't changed? How did you check if `data1` is changed or not?

Comment: Could you include code for setting state as well. The full code

Comment: @BorislavStefanov Everything seems OK. just try using await keyword in front of your axios call. Since our setData1([]) is an asynchronous call, I feel this should work.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather again sticking results...

Comment: @BorislavStefanov After setData1([]); write a console.log(data1) and see if it is an empty array. And Would like to know what exactly do you mean by 'sticking results" :) Thanks

Comment: No, it is not empty. It collects all the previous results, so the new result is concat to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Your Asynchronous handler `dataStruction` [closes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) over `data1` *before* a new render is triggered at `setData1([]);` (at the top of your `async` function).

[This happens because React state updates are batched and asynchronous.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

**Simple Solution:**

If you get rid of (delete the line) `setData1([]);` and change `setData1([...data1, { ...element1, level: 1 }]);` to `setData1([{ ...element1, level: 1 }]);` then you will get an array with a new element in it without preserving the "old" elements.

**Alternative Solution:**

You can also wrap your state updates into functions like so:

Turn this: `setState("foo")`

Into this: `setState((state, props) => "foo")`

The second form (passing a function instead directly a state) ensures that the correct state is referenced. So in your case the second state update would reference the updated state.